# Ubuntu 19.10 l2tp VPN doesn't work anymore

Tags: upgrade, vpn, 19.10, l2tp

After upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 19.10, my VPN connection doesn't work anymore.

My settings:

```
phase1: 3des-sha1;modp1024
phase2: 3des-sha1
```

This worked fine so far.
I checked the packages installed:

```
network-manager-l2tp 1.2.10-1; 
network-manager-l2tp-gnome 1.2.10-1; 
xl2tpd 1.3.12-1.1
libreswan 3.29-2
```

What can I do?

Comment: Without log output from `sudo journalctl -b`, it is hard to say what is going wrong. network-manager-l2tp 1.2.16-1 fixes some issues and may fix the issue you are having, but hard to say without knowing what the error messages say..

Comment: state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Ubuntu is not really happy with using 3des as handshake cipher, but I managed to make it work.

You may want to set the phase 1 and 2 algorithms using a final exclamation mark, like so:

Phase 1: `3des-sha1-modp1024!`
Phase 2: `3des-sha1!`

I tested this with network-manager-l2tp 1.2.10-1, network-manager-l2tp-gnome 1.2.10-1 and Ubuntu 19.10

Hope this solves your issue too.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10.  I tried the NetworkManager upgrade too, but that didn't solve my problem.  I then did the following three things, and now everything works again:

1. Replaced libreSwan with StrongSwan (I found if I purged libreSwan, StrongSwan was automatically installed)
2. Explicitly specified the Phase 1 and Phase 2 algorithms: "3des-sha1-modp1024" and "3des-sha1" respectively.
3. Ensured only MSCHAPv2 was checked under PPP Settings.

I have a feeling #3 is what solved my problem as I did notice a few more authentication boxes were checked under PPP Settings after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try the network-manager-l2tp 1.2.16-1 backport from the following PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp

With network-manager-l2tp 1.2.16-1, you should be able to delete the phase 1 & 2 algorithm entries as it now uses a merge of proposals from Win10 and iOS instead of using the libreswan or strongswan default set of proposals.

Comment: state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')  output of journal